# Write interrupt data into a Raspberry pi Register on C?

Tags: python, hardware, c, interrupts

I'm trying to read interrupts and detect direction of interrupts from an encoder using a raspberry pi ,  it is USdigital Brand
"H6BM-1000-500-IE-S-H" , it has 1000 signals per revolution , the thing is that when I run my python program , I loose some steps (probably because of python speed) , I switched from RPi.GPIO to pigpio , because pigpio is written in C , and got all the interrupts right , the thing is that when I add python code on the callback function it looses steps , leaving me on the same spot as before , my next idea is to write the encoder interrupt value into a Register on the raspberry pi , so on my python program I only need to read the value , like a link between python and C , but I dont know how to detect interrupts on C and write them into a register , any help?

new ideas are also welcome

heres my code till now

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import time
import math as m 
import pigpio # http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/python.html


class Signal(object):
    """docstring for Interrupt"""
    def __init__(self, pinA , pinB):
        self.pinA      = pinA
        self.pinB      = pinB
        self.gpio      = pigpio.pi()
        self.perimetro = 40*m.pi
        self.cuenta    = 0
        self.estado    = 0
        self.tiempo_actual = 0 
        self.tiempo_anterior = time.time()
        self.velocidad = 0

        #Definicion de funciones que correran al interrumpirse en los pines
        self.interrupcionA  = self.gpio.callback(self.pinA, edge = pigpio.FALLING_EDGE ,func = self.guia)
        #self.interrupcionB = self.gpio.callback(self.pinB, edge = pigpio.EITHER_EDGE , func = self.referencia)


    def guia(self,a,b,c):
        self.tiempo_actual = time.time()
        if int(self.gpio.read(self.pinB)):
            self.cuenta += 1

        if not int(self.gpio.read(self.pinB)):
            self.cuenta -= 1

        tiempo = self.tiempo_actual-self.tiempo_anterior
        self.tiempo_anterior  = self.tiempo_actual
        self.velocidad = (self.perimetro/1000)/tiempo
        print "cuenta en %s" % self.cuenta    



def main():

    encoder = Signal(21,20)
    try:
        while 1:
            time.sleep(1)       
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        pigpio.pi().clear_bank_1(bin(2**20+2**21))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: There are some pigpio encoder examples.  Python at http://abyz.co.uk/rpi/pigpio/examples.html#Python_rotary_encoder_py and C but using the daemon at http://abyz.co.uk/rpi/pigpio/examples.html#pdif2_RED.  The C code uses the same interface as Python but can handle far higher rotation rates.  At least try the Python example to ensure your implementation performs at least as well.

Comment: With pigpio you need to be using callbacks to monitor encoders.

Comment: thanks for your solution joan , it seems it will work , but is there a way I can write the value of the C program into a register? , I mean low level programing , just as a PIC microcontroller , that way I could easily be just reading it when needed from python , thanks

Comment: The best you could probably do is write the output to a pipe and have the Python read from the pipe.  It would be a bit of a kludge though.

Comment: Thank you very much for all your help , I've ran various tests on the rotary encoder you posted , and aparently python code of pigpio rotaryencoder solves my problem , should you answer it so I can mark your answer as best answer ? or should I answer it , I'm kind of new in this

Comment: You can answer your own question - in fact it is encouraged.  I can add a comment to your answer if I think it would be useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After making some tests , and thanks to joan's comments , I find the rotary encoder [library for python](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/examples.html#Python_rotary_encoder_py) enough to solve my problem , I modified it a little bit just to calculate velocity from interrupts and timestamps , that are suitable for what my application is (Programing and installing a PID{velocity , and position on cascade} for a stepper motor) this code captures all of my interrupts and rotation direction

here's the code I'm using

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import pigpio

class decoder:

   """Clase para decodificar los pulsos de un encoder mecanico."""

   def __init__(self, pi, gpioA, gpioB, callback):

      self.pi = pi
      self.gpioA = gpioA
      self.gpioB = gpioB
      self.callback = callback



      self.levA = 0
      self.levB = 0

      self.lastGpio = None

      self.pi.set_mode(gpioA, pigpio.INPUT)
      self.pi.set_mode(gpioB, pigpio.INPUT)

      self.pi.set_pull_up_down(gpioA, pigpio.PUD_UP)
      self.pi.set_pull_up_down(gpioB, pigpio.PUD_UP)

      self.cbA = self.pi.callback(gpioA, pigpio.EITHER_EDGE, self._pulse)
      self.cbB = self.pi.callback(gpioB, pigpio.EITHER_EDGE, self._pulse)

   def _pulse(self, gpio, level, tick):

      """
      Decode the rotary encoder pulse.

                   +---------+         +---------+      0
                   |         |         |         |
         A         |         |         |         |
                   |         |         |         |
         +---------+         +---------+         +----- 1

             +---------+         +---------+            0
             |         |         |         |
         B   |         |         |         |
             |         |         |         |
         ----+         +---------+         +---------+  1
      """

      if gpio == self.gpioA:
         self.levA = level
      else:
         self.levB = level;

      if gpio != self.lastGpio: # debounce
         self.lastGpio = gpio

         if   gpio == self.gpioA and level == 1:
            if self.levB == 1:
               self.callback(1)
         elif gpio == self.gpioB and level == 1:
            if self.levA == 1:
               self.callback(-1)

   def cancel(self):

      """
      Cancel the rotary encoder decoder.
      """

      self.cbA.cancel()
      self.cbB.cancel()

if __name__ == "__main__":

   import time
   import pigpio

   import rotary_encoder

   pos = 0
   actual_time = 0
   past_time = time.time()
   velocidad = 0
   def callback(way):

      global pos
      global past_time
      global tiempo_actual
      global velocidad
      actual_time = time.time()
      pos -= way
      time = actual_time - past_time
      velocidad = 0.06283185307179587/time #linear movement of machine from each step of stepper motor
      past_time = actual_time





   pi = pigpio.pi()

   decoder = rotary_encoder.decoder(pi, 21, 20, callback)
   while 1:

      time.sleep(1)
      print("pos={0} vel={1}".format(pos,velocidad))


   decoder.cancel()

   pi.stop()
```